# python ctypes callback may being ignore?

Tags: python-3.x, callback, ctypes

**I have a c callback with the following prototype:**

```
typedef void(__stdcall *TUSR_ConnAckEvent)( long ReturnCode, LPCWSTR Description );
```

**This callback function is meant to be user-defined**

```
boolean USR_OnConnAck(TUSR_ConnAckEvent OnConnAct);
```

user need use **USR_OnConnAck()** registration callback function,then user need to use **USR_Connect()** to initiate a connection to the server.If success,callback function should be working,but it's not, now I am confused.

**I have tried prototyping the callback multiple ways:**

1.

```
OnConnAck = WINFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_long, c_wchar_p)

@OnConnAck
def ConnAck_CBF(returnCode, description):
    print('Hello world')
    print(returnCode[0], description[0])
```

2.

```
OnConnAck = WINFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_long, c_wchar_p)
OnConnAct = OnConnAck(ConnAck_CBF)
```

after instantiating the correct arg and restypes for the function, however the callback is never called. I was hoping someone could point me towards any possible errors

**here is my code now:**

(by the way,my python's version is 3.6.5 and 32bit)

```
dll = windll.LoadLibrary("UsrCloud.dll")
def ConnAck_CBF(returnCode, description):
    print('Hello world')
    print(returnCode[0], description[0])

OnConnAck = WINFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_long, c_wchar_p)
dll.USR_Init.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_ushort, c_long]
dll.USR_Connect.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p]
dll.USR_OnConnAck.argtypes = [OnConnAck]
dll.USR_OnConnAck.restype = c_bool

OnConnAct = OnConnAck(ConnAck_CBF)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = "clouddata.usr.cn"
    port = 1883
    ver = dll.USR_GetVer()
    hadInit = c_bool(dll.USR_Init(host, port, ver))
    if hadInit.value:
        username = "sdktest"
        password = "sdktest"
        hadOnConn = c_bool(dll.USR_OnConnAck(OnConnAct))
        print(hadOnConn)
        if hadOnConn.value:
            dll.USR_Connect(username, password)
```

**here is the dll file:**
[UsrCloud.zip](http://cloud.usr.cn/sdk/dll/res/UsrCloud.zip)

**here is the all function prototypes that i has used:**

```
typedef long(_stdcall *FN_USR_GetVer)();
typedef boolean(_stdcall *FN_USR_Init)(LPCWSTR Host, unsigned short Port, long Ver);
typedef void(_stdcall *TUSR_ConnAckEvent)(long ReturnCode, LPCWSTR Description);
typedef boolean(_stdcall *FN_USR_OnConnAck)(TUSR_ConnAckEvent OnConnAct);
typedef boolean(_stdcall *FN_USR_Connect)(LPCWSTR Username, LPCWSTR Password);
```

**here is the document:**

http://cloud.usr.cn/Public/sdk/dll/index.html

(it's a Chinese website,you can use GoolgeTranslate to read it.)

Comment: Please show the function prototypes for all functions you are calling.  Are they all __stdcall?

Comment: yes,all of they are __stdcall.And i have updated my question,you can see it.